# improve growing cell array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, cluster-analysis

I would like to know how to efficiently run this part of my progam. Basically for a background of what I aim to do, I want to cluster points. There are around 10,000 points. These points have computed "forces" between them that is stored in matrix `F`. So the force between point 1 and point 2 is `F(1,2)`. I would then like to "cluster points" with sufficient `F` acting on them (Force setting/threshold), that is 2 points with sufficient `F` between them belong to the same cluster.

I have a code as seen below. A cell array `CLUSTER` was made to contain the cluster assignments. So `CLUSTER{i}` is the cell containing the `i`th cluster with clustered points in it.

However, for some `F` settings, the implementation takes forever. I have read about preallocation and `parfor` (`parfor` can't be done since there is dependency in iterations). But does preallocation of cell arrays mean that individual cells are not preallocated with memory? Is there any other way around this? Profiling tells me that `ismember` has the biggest share in computing. I hope to improve the code with your suggestions. Thanks a lot!

```
CLUSTER = {};

for fi = 1:srow 
    for fj = 1:scol 
        if fj > fi % to eliminate redundancy, diagonal mirror elements of F !check on this 
            if F(fi,fj) >= 2000 % Force setting    
                if( (~ismember(1,cellfun(@(x)ismember(fi,x),CLUSTER))) && (~ismember(1,cellfun(@(x)ismember(fj,x),CLUSTER))) ) % fi & fj are not in CLUSTER
                    CLUSTER{end+1} = [fi fj];
                    end
                %%if( (ismember(1,cellfun(@(x)ismember(fi,x),CLUSTER))) && (ismember(1,cellfun(@(x)ismember(fj,x),CLUSTER))) ) % fi & fj are in CLUSTER   
                    %do nothing since lfi and fj are in CLUSTER    
                %%end    
                if( (ismember(1,cellfun(@(x)ismember(fi,x),CLUSTER))) && (~ismember(1,cellfun(@(x)ismember(fj,x),CLUSTER))) ) % fi in CLUSTER, fj not in CLUSTER
                    c = find(cellfun(@(x)ismember(fi,x),CLUSTER));
                    CLUSTER{c} = [CLUSTER{c} fj];
                end        
                if( (~ismember(1,cellfun(@(x)ismember(fi,x),CLUSTER))) && (ismember(1,cellfun(@(x)ismember(fj,x),CLUSTER))) ) % fi not in CLUSTER, fj in CLUSTER
                    c = find(cellfun(@(x)ismember(fj,x),CLUSTER));
                    CLUSTER{c} = [CLUSTER{c} fi];
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: You say that `ismember` is that bottle neck. By calculating `ismember` once (for both fi and fj) your runtime would speed up a lot. Further vectorized operations are often faster, so you should try to vectorize the code. I am not 100% sure what you want, how many clusters do you want. Do you want 2 clusters? One with F(fi,fj)>2000 and the rest in another cluster. Is order important or do you only want to create some clusters of number of any order?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to clarify that I am creating a growing cell array CLUSTER with the cells CLUSTER{i} in it containing the clusters formed from points that were joined due to the sufficient F between them. Those points with insufficient F between them are not placed on cell array CLUSTER and are considered as noise. To illustrate a bit of this, Say we have Points 1 and 2 with F(1,2) = 2500. They are the first to be put in CLUSTER such that it becomes CLUSTER = {[1,2]}. Next, Points 1 and 3 with F(1,3) = 1500. So the cell array becomes CLUSTER = {[1,2]} again due to Point 3.

Comment: so to clarify, you want a 1 dimensional non nested cell where each element in the cell is the coordinate [i,j] (or rather each of them one 1x2 matrix for each element)? If this is correct, please respond

Comment: I think not quite. CLUSTER may result in something say CLUSTER = { [points in cluster 1] [points in cluster 2] [points in cluster 3]...[points in cluster n]}

Comment: I can give an example. F is a mirrored matrix along the diagonal for five points. Say F = [ 0,2000,2100,1800,1000; 2000,0,2200,1500,1700; 2100,2200,0,1300,1400; 1800,1500,1300,0,2200; 1000,1700,1400,2200,0] Then the cell array CLUSTER = { [1,2,3] [4,5] } for F>=2000.

Comment: still not getting it, what if 3-4 also would have more that 2000N between them? would the cluster be {[1,2,3,4] [4,5]} then? or would it be {[1,2,3] [3,4] [4,5]}? And what would happen if 2-3 <2000? What would that make of the cluster? You have not written the conditions for the cluster anywhere! What is a cluster? Can you give a **formal definition**? The definition from the questions is two points with an internal force exceeding a defined threshold. This would mean the there are exactly 2 elements for each cell.

Comment: As for the clustering definition according to the algorithm, 2 points with sufficient F between them belong to the same cluster. My bad if I may not have a better phrase. That is, a point say P is assigned to an existing nth cluster from the cell array CLUSTER if one or any of the points in that same nth cluster has an F >= threshold acting on P. So in your questions, if 3-4>2000 then CLUSTER = {[1,2,3,4,5]}. If 2-3<2000, then CLUSTER = {[1,2,3] [4,5]}. Even though F between 2 & 3 is <2000, 2 & 3 belong to the same cluster because of point 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the best way, but my thought is that this should be possible to do by some kind of update algorithm. Begin with looking at node 1. Find all the nodes clustered with node 1 as,

```
clusteredNbr = find(F(1,:)>=2000); (a)
```

This will give you the node number for all nodes that are clustered with node 1. Then find all nodes that is clustered with `clusteredNbr`, by repeting `(a)` with for all new nodes. These nodes can then be added to the same vector as the old nodes in `clusteredNbr`. You may have some duplicates here, but they can be removed later. Then check for new unique nodes in this resulting vector. If there are any, repeat `(a)` for these. Continue until you find all nodes in the first cluster. Then you know that any of the nodes in the first cluster is not clustered with the others.

Repeat this process for the next cluster and so on. The gain with this is that you use `find` instead of `ismember` and that the operation can be vectorized, which allows you to run only one for loop.

Comment: thanks a lot for this suggestion. i will try to do this and then get back with any of the results i get.